# Typescript Call method from constructor of the class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, typescript, angular-directive

I'm trying to call a method of a class constructor like so:

```
' var paddleCtrl = scope.paddleRanged;

        paddleCtrl.slider = slider;
        this.$paddleLeft = paddleCtrl.$paddleLeft = $(elem).find('.paddle-left'),
            this.$paddleRight = paddleCtrl.$paddleRight =  $(elem).find('.paddle-right'),
            this.$paddleRailActive = paddleCtrl.$paddleRailActive = $(elem).find('.paddle-rail .active'),
            this.$clickZone = paddleCtrl.$clickZone =  $(elem).find('.clickZone');

        this.paramsInit();
}'
```

Method is declared as follows: 
`paramsInit()  {
            console.log(this)
}`

But get this error: "this.paramsInit is not a function". I tried to declare a method like:

```
paramsInit = () => {
        console.log(this)
 }
```

But if the method call, then this refers to the Window object

Example on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/powerman23rus/pen/ONzZJZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by assigning a function "link" using the keyword "new".

For example:

```
console.clear();
class TestController{
  constructor(){

  }
}
class TestLink {
  constructor(scope, elem, attr, ctrl){
    console.log('Method call:')
    this.method();
    console.log('Method2 call:')
    this.method2();
    console.log('Method3 call:')
    this.method3();
  }
  method = () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
  method2 = function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
  method3() {
    console.log(this);
  }

}
class TestDirective {
  restrict='E';
  replace=true;
  scope={};
  controller=TestController;
  controllerAs='Test';
  bindTocOntroller=true;
  link=(scope, elem, attr)=>{
    return new TestLink(scope, elem, attr);
  };
  template='<p>Hello</p>'
}

angular.module('App', [])
  .directive('test', ()=>new TestDirective);
```

Code on [codepen](http://codepen.io/powerman23rus/pen/NNXMRo).

Comment: This doesn't explain why and the example doesn't have any comments or clue about what it is supposed to do. Please improve your answer so it's helpful for others.

Comment: And also note how you should put Codepen links (with their code also in the answer)